# in some situation, "A is type of B" could be shorten as "A is a B", is my understanding right?

Tags: meaning

This [post](https://www.askdifference.com/timber-vs-wood/) says

> The main difference between Timber and Wood is that the **Timber is a wood** that has been processed into beams and planks and Wood is a fibrous material from trees of other plants...
>
> Lumber (American English; used only in North America) or timber (used in the rest of the English speaking world) **is a type of wood** that has been processed into beams and planks ...

It seems that, in some situation, "A is a type of B" could be shorten as "A is a B", is my understanding right? if yes, what are the situations?

Answer (score 1):

You ask an insightful question, but one that concerns idiomatic usage, where general and useful rules are hard to come by. For the following equivalence

> **A** is *a type* of **B** ←→ **A** is *a* **B**

to hold, English must recognize that the phrase with the indefinite article "a **B**" means the class of things represented by **B**. For instance, the following works as you suggested:

> **The Indian tiger** is *a type* of **cat** ←→ **The Indian tiger** is *a* **cat**

because the genus *Felis* is captured by the phrase "a cat."

Your example

> ***** **Timber** is *a type* of **wood** ←→ **Timber** is *a* **wood**

is problematic because "a wood" can mean a specific species of tree which supplied the wood, say walnut or oak. To get your meaning requires dropping the article:

> Timber is wood that has been processed....

meaning that timber is any kind of wood that has been processed.

To take another example that doesn't work, consider

> ***** **Embarrassment** is *a type* of **shame** ←→ **Embarrassment** is *a* **shame**

The reason is that the expression "Something is a shame" has the idiomatic meaning that the "Something" is shameful, not that it's a particular type of shame.

And in this example

> ***** **Carbon-14** is *a type* of **carbon** ←→ **Carbon-14** is *a* **carbon**.

the problem is that "a carbon" isn't a term for all isotopes of carbon.

It's a natural question to ask (linguistically) how cats, wood, embarrassment, and C-14 differ amongst each other, but I know of no general rule to guide the classification.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Does "recognize" in "English must recognize that the phrase with the indefinite article "a B" means the class of things represented by B" mean "identify"?

Comment: Sorry that I wasn't clear. Let me try again. The indefinite article *a* most commonly identifies one particular thing from a class of like things. So when I say, "*A* cat ran quietly across the room," you know I'm there's one particular thing (It happens to be a cat) that crossed the room noiselessly. In the example, we're talking about a grouping (the [species] Indian tiger) that's a member of the class of thing it belongs to. That class (with many members) sometimes can be defined by a single representative member (*a* cat). Does that help or hurt?